# Fastest way to count sequence elements satisfying a predicate

Tags: python, performance, generator, list-comprehension

I want to count the elements verifying a certain property in a throw-away sequence. I am somewhat surprised that a generator expression would not be the fastest one:

```
from random import random
l = [random() for i in range(1000000)]
%timeit len([None for x in l if x < 0.5])
%timeit len([x for x in l if x < 0.5])
%timeit sum(1 for x in l if x < 0.5)
%timeit sum(x < 0.5 for x in l)
```

Measured performances:

```
90.7 ms ± 7.59 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
97.7 ms ± 7.23 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
105 ms ± 3.66 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
178 ms ± 2.38 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried `itertools.filterfalse()`?

Comment: No, I was told that lambda functions were not particularly efficient in Python.

Answer (score 2):

You can use NumPy, if the conversion to an NumPy array itself does not count:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array(l)
%timeit np.sum(a < 0.5)

1.28 ms ± 48.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Even taking the conversion into account makes it significantly faster:

```
%%timeit 
a = np.array(l)
np.sum(a < 0.5)

27.2 ms ± 433 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Compared to the pure Python versions on my machine.

```
from random import random
l = [random() for i in range(1000000)]
%timeit len([None for x in l if x < 0.5])
%timeit len([x for x in l if x < 0.5])
%timeit sum(1 for x in l if x < 0.5)
%timeit sum(x < 0.5 for x in l)

46.4 ms ± 941 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
48.1 ms ± 1.25 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
59.5 ms ± 811 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
103 ms ± 1.49 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: I am not familiar with NumPy, but this sounds very interesting. Any caveat? Does NumpPy arrays support all Python types? heterogeneous elements?

Comment: No heterogeneous elements. Fixed-size, homogeneous arrays only.  As the name suggests it target numbers.

Comment: Thanks for these precisions :)

Comment: This should work for anybody, thanks :) My question was just out of curiosity: I always wonder what is the fastest way to do this sort of thing (on sequences of numbers, strings, or whatever).

Comment: Great. BTW, you can express this by accepting this answer. ;)

Comment: That's why I have upvoted your answer. For the moment, I don't want to accept it, since it may discourage other users to come out with a more general answer. Sorry, and thanks again!